# Jquery offset function making the top style a negative number in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, dom, css-position

I am tying to create a custom alert box with fixed positioning. It works great in chrome, but I can't get the dynamic position right in Firefox.

I set a modal container to equal the size of the document

```
$('#modalContainer').height($.getDocHeight());
```

and then the #alertBox div lives within modalContainer and has position:fixed style.

I am using the jquery offset function to set the top and left values for #alertBox like so:

```
var off_top=$(window).height()/3-$('#alertBox').height()/3;
var off_top=100;
var off_left=$(window).width()/2- $('#alertBox').width()/2;
$('#alertBox').offset({top:off_top,left:off_left});
```

In chrome the top value gets set to 100px and show up on the screen. In firefox, I get an obnoxiously large number for the top value like -1084px.

When I output both the .offset() values and position() values to console.log, they are the same in chrome. However in firefox, while the offset value outputs exactly what I set it to, the .position() function outputs the obnoxiously large number.

Is this a known browser inconsistency? Do I need to go about this a different way?

Comment: If it is `fixed` positioning, why not use css `top` and `left` around 40-50% to center the box. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/XWN9G/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your initial position as

```
$('#modalContainer').height(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

That should get you the [height of the viewport](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html#link12).

As an alternative to calculating your offset every time you could do use `margin: auto` and `position: absolute` on your alert box.  You'll still probably want to set the modal container height, but all the alert's centering will be done automatically.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<p>Lorum ipsum ... </p>
<div id='modalContainer'>
    <div id='alertBox'>
        <h1>Beware!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#modalContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#alertBox {
    width: 300px; /*sample*/
    height: 200px; /*sample*/
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#modalContainer').height(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used a combination of this answer as well as some of what I had. Absolute positioning did not work when the browser was scrolled, so I kept position:fixed, and added a margin value. When I did this I did not need to dynamically alter the top value. To get the box to horizontally centered, I still used the left offset, because the auto margin style was not taking. I think that is because I was dynamically adding and removing #alertBox.

Comment: @Ed Sullivan Good to know.  Makes me curious if setting position of #modalContainer to fixed would work.  Might have to try that.

Comment: I am not sure that would work in this instance. modalContainer needs to cover the entire body, so that other properties with lower z-indexes can not be clicked.